# Bolder question title font

Tags: discussion, design

I find the question title font too thin, on question pages and to some extent on the `/questions` as well. The titles don't stand out enough to my tastes.

The same font is used on [CSTheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions). I find it less objectionable there thanks to the monochrome background.

(If the font choice depends on my browser settings, please tell me what to report, on Firefox or Chrome.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the font looks better on questions you haven't clicked yet. Your problem appears only after I've clicked them. Can you check? Maybe the color for 'clicked' links is one that should change.

Comment: Indeed it looks better in the unclicked style, but it's still not as visible as I'd like.