# Better question title font

Tags: discussion, design

So I happened to notice a new font for question titles at [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). I rather like it.

[image: MSO title font]

It reminds me that I'm [not too fond of Unix & Linux's title font](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/bolder-question-title-font). That's a main text font, but I don't think it's well suited to things like command names which we're normally used to seeing in a monospace font, like `find` below (an especially jarring case due to the ligature).

[image: Unix title font]

Now I wouldn't want MSO's font here, because a sans serif font where I is the same as l is not good either. The font used on the Trilogy, sans serif but with a hint on the `l`, isn't too bad.

[image: SU title font]

Can we have Computer Modern (I like Computer Modern, especially the tt font)? Failing that, can we have the trilogy title font? Or, really, any better font for titles on a site where title often contain command names?

[image: please]

Comment: Preferably one that includes slashed or dotted zeros... http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716/question-title-font-renders-0-number-zero-much-like-o-lower-case-letter

Comment: I wouldn't mind the ponies.

Comment: It's Liberation Serif now, since apparently y'all like serifs more than SO does.

Comment: Unfortunately [the old serif font is back](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3429/site-design-updates).

Comment: @Gilles Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Liberation Serif was the font in the question title before the conversion and it's the font now. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I don't remember the history of title font changes, but IIRC at some point we did have a better title font. Then it went back to the current style of serif font that's fine for a non-technical site but looks ugly when used to typeset a mixture of English and code. I think you've turned off the `fi` ligature, which is on the right track (but more importantly, please turn off double quote rewriting!). But really this site needs a title font that's suitable for bits of code, like what the Trilogy had, I think, up to its latest redesign.

Comment: @gilles Personally, I'd be happy to change the title font. Let me double check with a few others to be sure there's not a reason it is like it is now.

Answer (score 2):

It's Liberation Serif now, since apparently y'all like serifs more than SO does.

– [Shog9](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/800/better-question-title-font#comment1805_800)